# Implementing version history with a closure table schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, versioning, transitive-closure-table

I have a custom CMS implementation that stores content nodes in two tables as described in the "closure table" section at http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data and using this gem https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree under Ruby on Rails 3 and MySQL.

The time has come for me to implement a version history where any change in the content tree (editing, inserting, moving, deleting nodes, etc.) would create a new version of the root node (a publication). And users would be able to look at older versions and revert back to them. The revert action would create a newer version which is a copy of the reverted one.

Is there a well known way to achieve this? or does anyone have an idea or example implementation for this sort of thing?

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[State machines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines)? I am curious if there are more ideas . I know for sure there is a brilliant solution , but it is out of Rails scope . This is document management system . The first I would recommend is Alfresco .